# How to connect Visual Studio to Aurora MySQL DB?

Tags: mysql, visual-studio, entity-framework, amazon-aurora

In Visual Studio 2019 menu: Tools -> Connect To Database I see "MySQL Database" data provider, but an attempt to connect to my aurora database finishes with weird error:

"Microsoft Visual Studio / **Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts. Sequence contains more than one matching element**"

I have Aurora DB based on MySQL 5.6.10. I can connect to it using the latest MySQL Workbench 8.0.18. I have the latest "MySQL for Visual Studio 1.2.9" and Connector/NET 8.0.18. I work with .NET Framework 4.7.2. I can also connect to other (normal) MySQL instances from the Visual Studio, but not to Aurora DB.

My final target is to create ADO.NET Entity Data Model from the amazon db, but this fails on the same error message.

Is there any guide how to connect MySQL Aurora DB with .NET Framework (not .NET Core)? A guide to extremely simple application which can download single value from any table would mean a significant step forward for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. I found it's a [Bug #97448](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=97448) introduced in MySql.Data 8.0.18. Workaround is to define server name by IP address instead of xxx.rds.amazonaws.com address.

Answer (score 0):

It's a [know bug](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=97448).

FYI the previous version of `mysql.data` (v6.10.9) is also affected.

As a workaround you could resolve the DNS value to an IP address manually.

In the code example below I check if the server value is an IP then I resolve the DNS name when the value is not an IP address.

```cs
if (IPAddress.TryParse(server, out var ipAddress))
{
    // The server value is an IP address, it can be used directly
}
else
{
    server = Dns.GetHostEntry(server).AddressList.FirstOrDefault()?.MapToIPv4().ToString();
}

return new MySqlConnectionStringBuilder
       {
           Server = server
           // ...
       };
```